# Recuperar todos os valores de um tabela SQL e adicionar a uma sessão

Tags: sql

Eu estou utilizando o seguinte código para pegar todos os dados da minha tabela:

```
$sql4 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM login");
$exibe4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4);
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente e está pegando todos os dados normais.

Porém, antes quando era um dado especifico eu adicionava a `session` assim:

```
$_SESSION['diasvip']=$exibe['diasvip'];
```

Porém, agora como eu quero TODOS os dados não sei como fazer!

```
$_SESSION['dados']=$exibe4['*'];
```

Obviamente que com esse asterisco não funcionaria, mas só para ilustrar o meu objetivo mesmo.

Comment: Se `dados` é um array, basta fazer `$_SESSION['dados']= $exibe4` acho que deve funcionar.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora! Aqui está parte do código: http://pastebin.com/razYfk8Y

Comment: Guilherme, esse código é irrelevante para a questão, já conseguiu resolver?